# Сокеты. Прием от сервера массива данных

Tags: java, java-8

Имеется сервер который слушает команды от подключившихся клиентов. При обработке команды(запросов) клиенту отправляется массив данных. Проблема с приемам массива данных, после вывода данных сервера в цикле клиент зависает и дальше не идет по коду. Использовал для приема и передачи пакетов сокета: `BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));` и `PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());`

Answer (score 1):

Есть похожие вопросы: [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479697/printwriter-or-any-other-output-stream-in-java-do-not-know-r-n) и [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480894/java-server-client-readline-method)

Ну а по-существу - это вопрос, как вы читаете данные от сервера на клиенте и делает ли сервер flush для PrintStream'a.

Так работает:

**Сервер**

```
public class ServerExample implements Runnable {

    Socket clientSocket;

    public ServerExample(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            System.out.println("Accepted connection from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + clientSocket.getPort());
            writer.println("Waiting for commands from client");
            writer.println("Supported commands:");
            writer.println("  GET");
            writer.println("  CLOSE");
            writer.println();
            while (clientSocket.isConnected()) {
                System.out.println("waiting for command...");
                String line = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("command: " + line);
                if ("close".equalsIgnoreCase(line) || (null == line)) {
                    System.out.println("Closing connection with " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" + clientSocket.getPort());
                    writer.println("server is closing connection");
                    break;
                } else if ("get".equalsIgnoreCase(line)) {
                    System.out.println("sending data to client...");
                    // отправляем "массив" чисел клиенту
                    IntStream.range(1, 5).forEach(writer::println);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            writer.close();
            clientSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 9876;

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT)) {
            System.out.println("Server is listening on 127.0.0.1:" + SERVER_PORT);
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new Thread(new ServerExample(socket)).start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Клиент**

```
public class ClientExample {

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 9876;

    public static void readSocket(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(10); // Чтобы сервер успел прислать данные и reader.ready() вернул true
        while(reader.ready())
            System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), SERVER_PORT);

        PrintWriter writer    = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        readSocket(reader);

        System.out.println("\n1st call to GET command");
        writer.println("GET");
        readSocket(reader);

        System.out.println("\n2nd call to GET command");
        writer.println("GET");
        readSocket(reader);

        System.out.println("\ncall to CLOSE command");
        writer.println("CLOSE");
        readSocket(reader);
    }
}
```